# How to copy data from abc table to abc log table in MySQL from SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to copy data from abc table to abc log table in MySQL from SQL Query?

Table `abc`:-
Column:-

```
   cuto_id (AutoIncrement)
   first_name
   last_name
   .... n number columns
```

Table `abc_log`:-
Column:-

```
   id (AutoIncrement)
   cuto_id 
   first_name
   last_name
   .... n number columns
```

Comment: Insert..Select from abc. BTW it's not a good idea to have white space in column names.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  insert into abc_log ( 'First Name', 'last name' )
  select 'First Name', 'last name' from abc
```

search for `GROUP_CONCAT` in MYSQL with `dynamic sql` to create column name dynamically and use it in you query.

It is something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`') ORDER BY column_name),'')
FROM   `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE  `table_schema`=DATABASE() AND `table_name`='abc'
INTO @sql;

set @query = Concat("insert into abc_log (",  @sql ,") select ",  @sql ,"  from abc") ;
select @query
```

Comment: You need to lose the square brackets and substitute backticks in mysql

Comment: Very thanks for your reply but I have many columns(About 50) in abc table. and don't want to define all columns.

Comment: No `INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)`  does not do make Dynamic SQL..  `INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)` is a string function to insert a string into the middle of a other string..

Comment: If you have 50 columns but cant' be bothered to retype them then mysql does not have an easy solution for you. You could of course Describe the table drop the result into notepad(if on windows) and use windows features to delete the bits of the row you don't want (shift-end) at least that way you minimise the retyping and the names will be correct.

Comment: @Dhiru: please check my updated ans, hope that exactly what do you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without dynamic SQL:

```
-- create the structure of the table
create table abc_log as
    select abc.*
    from abc
    where 1=0;

-- add the id column
alter table abc_log add id auto_increment primary key first;

-- insert the data
insert into abc_log
    select null, abc.*
    from abc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6032d0cf16deafd9c72e561cfbe2fb82) is a db<>fiddle that illustrates the process.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command.

```
Insert into abc_log(select * from abc)
```

Comment: Won't work because of auto_increment column in log.

Comment: I am getting error 'Column count doesn't match value count'..:)

Comment: While it is valid SQL defined in the standards, you ideally not be using/trusting the implicit column(s) definition always define explicit column(s) like `INSERT INTO abc_log (<columns>) VALUES(...) / INSERT INTO abc_log (<columns>) SELECT (<columns>) ....`  @Dhiru those ones are much less error prone..

Comment: In the log table, we have another id (AutoIncrement) column. so please recheck your table structure. I already tried friend.

Comment: I Didn't  saw that, try this one ,

insert into abc_log( cuto_id ,First Name , Last Name) (select * from abc)

Comment: thanks @Raymond..actually I could not want to do that..if I will not get any alternative solution then I have to do.

Comment: @LS that won't work because of the white spaces in the column names.

Comment: @P.Salmon It just an example use your original column name in there :)

Answer (score 0):

First create table

```
CREATE TABLE `abc_log` like `abc`;
```

then copy the data

```
INSERT INTO `abc_log` SELECT * FROM `abc`;
```

*Note*: If your `abc_log` table is not same as `abc` try to drop `abc_log` 
 and create with above statement.

Comment: Sorry friend, But I have to take one extra Primary Column in abc_log. because the log table is storing the abc table record history.